# Minkowski Sum Algorithm

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces, algorithms

I am trying to program the following algorithm to calculate the minkowski sum of two convex polygons: [Taken from Computational Geometry Algorithms and Applications (ISBN 978-3-540-77974-2) (Year 2008, Page 295)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5BzH.jpg)

It already works for simple polygons, but when I have something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejZKJ.jpg), the condition to end the loop is never reached. The thing is, beta (2*PI) is always bigger than every angle of the w-Polygon. So according to the algorithm, only j gets increased in every iteration (i can never reach n+1).
I could assume that beta is 0, but then alpha will always be the biggest angle and the loops end condition will never be reached too.
What I am I missing?

Comment: Once you've exhausted all the edges of one polygon, stop using that polygon.  Basically if j=m+1 you should only be adding edges from i.